# Can't find drivers for my WLAN laptop card

Tags: laptop, drivers, toshiba-laptop, wifi-driver

According to:

http://www.pcidatabase.com/search.php?device_search_str=4220&device_search=Search

My laptop has the folloiwng WLAN card:

```
Device Id:
0x4220

Chip Description:
Intel 54 MBit/s Notebook WLAN Card

Vendor Id:
0x8086

Vendor Name:
Intel Corporation
```

On the toshiba wlan driver download page, I can't see that card listed.

http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/wlan/?page=downloads

Not sure what I've done wrong.

I have an old Toshiba Tecra A2 laptop.

Comment: What OS are you running?  Seems unlikely that any modern OS wouldn't have a driver that supported your card out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8086:4220 is the Intel PRO/Wireless 2200.